# Pochhammer(x,n) for Negative x - Does any one know how to deal with this in Matlab etc?

Tags: combinatorics, matlab

I've tried to use a script that evaluates the Pochhammer symbol (rising factorial) in Matlab, but it fails to evaluate Pochhammer(x,n) whenever x is a negative number even though the expression is valid when x is negative (wolfram alpha and mathematica give answers for stuff like Pochhammer(-3,2)).

Can anyone help me get Pochhammer working in Matlab for negative arguments?

Thanks in advance,

Alex

Comment: This was posted to numerous sites apparently. I answered the actual question [on StackOverflow Matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18135186/using-the-pochhammer-symbol-in-matlab).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're not doing anything too computing intensive, just write your own:

```
function p = rising_factorial(x, n)
    p = 1; 
    for k = 0:(n - 1)
        p = p * (x + k); 
    end
end
```

Also this might be off-topic. Stack overflow may be better-suited.

Comment: this has a typo/bug, the number of values you are multiplying is not n

Comment: Woops, thanks for catching that.

Comment: Perfect, this works great. Thanks.

Comment: Can I ask: should this method work for any real x? I thought that the factorial is only defined for integer x - the gamma function has to be used when x is not an integer, and the gamma function is not used here. Should it still work for any real x?

Comment: Yes, it works for any real $x$.

Comment: Any real `x` until double precision overflows... By the way, that Matlab code could be simplified and greatly sped up with `p = prod(x+(0:n-1));`.

Comment: Use @horchler's code snippet instead. MATLAB performs much better when using operations that have been defined to take advantage of vector instructions.